# PHP sort inside loop

Tags: php, sorting, loops

I want to sort stuff while looping

```
$arr = array('c','a''b');
 foreach($arr as $alpha){
  sort($alpha);
  echo $alpha."-";
 }
```

and it should end up with a-b-c
how to get it done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = array('c','a', 'b');
sort($arr);
foreach($arr as $alpha) {
    echo $alpha . "-";
}
```

Sort only needs to be called once.

Comment: And for printing use implode instead of looping.